# Reading first letter of a word and choosing its number of alphabet

Tags: java

I want to use a scanner to import a word. Then use a string to only use 1 letter and after this lookup which letter is which number and then println it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your question? I suggest you start by writing the code required as much as you can by yourself, and ask a specific question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = scanner.nextLine();
    char letter = text.charAt(0);
    if(letter>='A' && letter<='Z')
        System.out.println((int)letter-(int)'A'+1);
    if(letter>='a' && letter<= 'z')
        System.out.println((int)letter-(int)'a'+1);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `-1`be `+1`? Anyway, +1

Comment: yeah+1 :D sorry... I'll fix it

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the first part of your question but, if you want to find out the letter of the alfabet, you could do this:

```
String scannedString = "WhateverYouScan"
char first = scannedString.toLowerCase().chatAt(0);
char alfabetNumber = first - 'a';
System.out.println(alfabetNumber);
```